# How do I assign weight to each observation of the data in weighted least square fitting?

Tags: regression

Suppose I have  a dataset { p1, p2,...pN}, where pi=(xi,yi), i=1,2,..., N.

How do I assign weight wi to each data point pi in weighted least square fitting?
Could any one help me? I'm not statistician. I have  just little knowledge about Statistics.

Answer (score 5):

Assume that the basic model is 
$$y_i=\mathbf x_i^T \boldsymbol \beta+\epsilon_i,$$
then weighted least squares can be written in the transformation
$$\sqrt{w_i}y_i=\sqrt{w_i}\mathbf x_i^T \boldsymbol \beta+\sqrt{w_i}\epsilon_i,$$
i.e., we regress $\sqrt{w_i}y_i$ on $\sqrt{w_i}\mathbf x_i$. Thus we have the weighted sum of squared residuals,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i}(y_i-\mathbf x_i^T \boldsymbol \beta)^2.$$
The objective is to minimize the weighted sum of squared residuals. Therefore, the estimates of the parameters are the solution for the following modified normal equations,
$$\mathbf{\left(X^TWX\right)\hat {\boldsymbol {\beta}}=X^TWy},$$
where $\mathbf{W}=\mathrm{diag}(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)$. We usually use the inverse of the variance of error term as the weights, $$w_i\propto\mathrm{var}(\epsilon_i)^{-1}.$$ The idea is that the observation with higher variance would have lower weight.

- If the **weights (or variance structure) are known**, say $\mathrm{var}(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^{2}x_i^2$ or $\mathrm{var}(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^{2}x_i$, we can directly use weights $w_i=x_i^{-2}$ or $w_i=x_i^{-1}$.
- Unfortunately, for most cases, the **weights (or variance structure) are unknown**, we need to use one of the following methods:

  - Use **residual plot** of the squared residuals against the predictor $x_i$ (or the fitted values $\hat y=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i$) to detect possible variance structure.
  - Use **formal test** to detect the variance structure, see the Page 196 of [the reference](http://emlab.berkeley.edu/eml/ra_reader/14-wls.pdf).
  - Iteratively reweighted least squares (IRWLS) to model the variance structure at each iteration step, e.g. $\mathrm{var}(\epsilon_i)=\gamma_0+\gamma_1x_i$ by regressing $\hat\epsilon^2_i$ on $x_i$.
  - Use the likelihood method to simultaneously estimate the mean parameters $\boldsymbol \beta$ and the variance parameters $\boldsymbol\gamma$.

Comment: Dear I'm not using software. I want to fit linear least square model on the data points {p1, p2, ...., pN} by weighted least square method. I need just simple formula to assign weight wi to each data point pi=(xi,yi). I want to solve this problem mathematically.

Comment: Please see my revision above, @Mustafa. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Please add little more detail as I'm not statistician. I read page on Wikipedia and found wi=1/(sigma_{i})^2. It seems to be strange to me. How can I compute sigma_{i}. I have data like {p1, p2, ...., pN}.Put i=1 then what does mean sigma_{1}?

Comment: @Mustafa, I previously thought the weights are known, so more details about your question are also helpful. I edited my answer, and provided the link about how to calculate the variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Ok I write more detail: weights wi are unknown. I have data points {p1, p2, ...., pN}, where pi=(xi,yi). I want to assign weight w5 (say) to  p5. then how can I compute the vale of w5? You said, "The idea is that the observation with higher variance would have lower weight".

Comment: Ok I write more detail: weights wi are unknown. I have data points {p1, p2, ...., pN}, where pi=(xi,yi). I want to assign weight w5 (say) to  p5. then how can I compute the value of w5? You said, "The idea is that the observation with higher variance would have lower weight". I get confused here. How can I find variance of p5=(3, 2) (say)? What is the formula to find w5? If w5= 1/(sigma_{5})^{2} then what does mean sigma_{5}?

Comment: I see your problem. Please see my revision above. You only have one point for each observation, so the variance cannot be calculated explicitly.

Comment: Hello. Before the weight adjustments do we subtract the means from both dependent and independent variables?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc it's not necessary, as shown in the equations in the answer.

Comment: So the intercept can be assumed to be part of the design matrix X as a vector of 1s, and there is nothing wrong with multiplying it with an inverse of a covariance matrix?

Comment: Yes @CagdasOzgenc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not statistician either but, as a physicist, I encountered several times this situation and I tried to make my personal philosoply. So, please, just consider this answer as a very personal opinion.

Let me consider a set of data points [X(i) , Y(i)] with no information about variance and say that we want to minimize a weighted sum of squares. If the range covered by the Y's is very large, the points with the largest values of Y are really those which define the regression. So, in such a case, what I minimize if the sum of the squares of relative errors on the Y's which then corresponds to a weight equal to [1 / Y(i)]^2. In such a situation, all points have the same importance. Otherwise, I do not weight my data.

For sure, I could produce counter arguments to that : points with very low Y's for example.

Comment: I could not understand. could you write more detail of your comments: "So, in such a case, what I minimize if the sum of the squares of relative errors on the Y's which then corresponds to a weight equal to [1 / Y(i)]^2. In such a situation, all points have the same importance. Otherwise, I do not weight my data."

Comment: Could you explain more your sentence: "So, in such a case, what I minimize if the sum of the squares of relative errors on the Y's which then corresponds to a weight equal to [1 / Y(i)]^2. In such a situation, all points have the same importance2.

Comment: @Mustafa. Just write your sum of squares as Sum[residue(i)^2] where residue(i) is (Y_calc(i) - Y_exp(i)) / Y_exp(i). For sure, if you use linear regression, you need to derive the value of the parameters from the derivatives of your objective function with respect to the parameters. This changes the classical expressions.

Comment: I explain my question again: I'm dealing with simple problem. I have data set { p1=(1,2), p2=(2,3), p3=(3,1),p4=(5,2)}. I want to fit a linear model by weighted least square fitting. Let w1 is the weight corresponding to the point p1=(1,2). Then tell me please what will be w1. What I understand is wi=1/yi i.e w1=1/2, w2=1/3,w3=1/1, w4=1/2. Is it write? I do not have any other information structure of the data.

Comment: If you want to minimize the sum of squares of relative errors, the weights would be 4, 9, 1 and 4.

Comment: Do you mean 1/4, 1/9,1/1 and 1.4? i.e. by taking wi=(1/yi)^2. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am sorry for the typo. I gave you the inverse of the weights instead of the weights.

Comment: Thanks for providing me easy way of assigning weights to data points

Comment: @Mustafa. I am glad to have helped. If you liked it, you can accept it.